# ios hidden modal controller navbar under parent navbar in ios7

Tags: ios, navbar, modalviewcontroller

lately I came across a strange thing while working on one application for iOS. While testing it on my iphone 5 (iOS 8) everything went fine. Then I discovered that the app runs slightly different on iOS 7.

When I am presenting a ViewController modally on iOS 7, the navigation bar of the modal view is hidden behind the one presented currently on screen.

I have no navigation controller embedded in the modal VC, I also tried to change the Navigation bar into a plain View -> The same happens.

I am presenting the Modal View Controller as I should with :

```
    [self presentViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I don't really know what else to do, I scanned the code, the Interface builder, everything and I cant figure out, how to make it work. Can you please give me a hint ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open storyboard and check if "Inferred" is selected on TopBar voice in Simulated metric section.
If it is selected, choose none.

If doesn't work - Step 2:
Check if Full screen mode is selected in Presentation voice.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it